# prevent requests-mock from lower casing my post data

Tags: python, python-requests, requests-mock

When using requests-mock, my querystring data is lowercased:

```
request.post('http://foo.bar', params={'Foo': 'Bar'})

def foo_bar(self, request, context):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

The actual value of `request.qs` will be `{'foo': ['bar']}`.

How do I get it to not lower case my query string data?

There's a bug that should be fixed in 1.1: https://bugs.launchpad.net/requests-mock/+bug/1584008

I'm using 1.3 though and still having this issue.

Comment: Are you sure? Try: `requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data={'Foo': 'Bar'}).json()`. `Foo` and `Bar` **are not lowercased**. Where are you reading your `qs` from?

Comment: Also, if you [search `requests`](https://github.com/requests/requests/search?p=1&q=lower&unscoped_q=lower) code, the only place `lower()` is used in a destructive manner is for headers, not for form parameters.

Comment: @randomir Sorry, that should be `params` and not `data`. Using `params`, I assume, will send the POST as querystring, and thus it shows up in `resp.qs`. Using `data` sends it as raw data and it shows up in `resp.text`. In both scenarios `resp.json()` will be empty.

Comment: @dan-klasson can you edit your question to make a reproducible example, for example using `'http://httpbin.org/post'` as in @randomir's comment?

Comment: @dan-klasson, you are still not telling us everything :) Because `requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', params={'Foo': 'Bar'}).json()` still shows proper query string is sent (case preserved).

Comment: @randomir Yes you're right. `qs` seems to come from requests mock library.

Comment: Should be fixed in 1.3 which is what I'm using though: https://bugs.launchpad.net/requests-mock/+bug/1584008

Comment: That's why it's useful to include a MVC example - not only to help answerers, but also for sanity check. :)

Comment: @randomir Yeah, down with the flu, not thinking straight. Still doesn't solve my problem though.

Comment: So I would recommend you close this question, and open a new one, in which you'll include the exact and complete problem you're trying to solve. I.e. a minimal code segment that reproduces the problem (or bug). Because right now, this question is unanswerable.